# I need a query to get result from the jpa repository

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, subquery, jpql

I have two tables (`policy`, `claims`) join by `policyId`, I need the details of the `Policy` from `Claims` by counting the no of claims against the each Policy and the checking the count value > parameter provided.

`PolicyClaim` is the policy object in `Claims`.

```
@Query("Select c.policyClaim from Claims c Where (Select count(c.claimId) From Claims c Group By c.PolicyClaim) > :countvalue")
```

I'm expecting the Detail of `Policy` table which satify the criteria.

I'm getting this error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception
>   is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: What do the Policy and Claims tables look like?  You are not currently joining them in the example query provided.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your example you don't need a nested query. Try this to simplify:

```java
@Query("Select c.policyClaim from Claims c Group By c.policyClaim Having count(c.claimId)  > :countvalue")
```

Edit: Based on your comment of a build error and not having a full picture of your table schemas or class definitions, I would suggest the following:

```java
@Query("SELECT p FROM Claims c INNER JOIN c.policyId p GROUP BY c.policyId HAVING COUNT(c.claimId) > :countvalue")
```

Comment: It's not working using this is giving me error during build